# Connect to multiple database source using entity framework using dynamically generated connection string?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, asp.net-web-api2

Connection to database using entity framework.

Connection string is generated dynamically based on user choice from UI.

The scenario is that user select some connection from UI and based on that selection entity framework has to connect for database queries.

The code below is used to generate entity connection string. But it's not working as supposed to be.

Entity partial class used to pass connection string.

```
public partial class Entities
{
   public Entities(string connectionName)
      : base(connectionName)
    {
    }
}

public static void GenerateEntityConnectionString(string serverName, string databaseName, string providerName,
      string databaseUserId, string databasePassword, short? databaseTimeout)
{
   string connnectionString = string.Empty;
   // Specify the provider name, server and database.
   //string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
   //string serverName = ".";
   //string databaseName = "AdventureWorks";

   // Initialize the connection string builder for the
   // underlying provider.
   SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder =
            new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

   // Set the properties for the data source.
   sqlBuilder.DataSource = serverName;
   sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
   sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
   sqlBuilder.UserID = databaseUserId;
   sqlBuilder.Password = databasePassword;
   sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
   sqlBuilder.ConnectTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(databaseTimeout);

   // Build the SqlConnection connection string.
   string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

   // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
   EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder =
            new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

   //Set the provider name.
   entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;

   // Set the provider-specific connection string.
   entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

   // Set the Metadata location.
   entityBuilder.Metadata  = @"res://*/EF.EntitiesModal.csdl|res://*/EF.EntitiesModal.ssdl|res://*/EF.EntitiesModal.msl";
   //entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/";
   connnectionString = entityBuilder.ConnectionString;

   ConnectionString = connnectionString;
}
```

**Updated**
While using connection string generated dynamically, entity framework is generating error i.e invalid object name. Though table exist in database.

Check image below for better understanding.

[image]

Table exist check image below:

[image]

> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand
>   t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget
>   target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)

[image]

Comment: Please supply more information about what isn't working. Are there any runtime errors? What is the output that you are getting?

Comment: @kettch I had updated the question including more details. I tried to connect using dynamic generated connection string. I am getting error **Invalid object dbo.table_name** though table exist in database. Have a look at images above. :(

Comment: What is the actual string you get from `GenerateEntityConnectionString` ?